# How to crosscompile qt applications with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, cross-platform, cross-compiling

The situation is:

There is a compiled qt application for different platforms: Linux, Windows, Android (soon and Mac) on the Linux host. I need to build an application for all platforms on a Linux host.

I used qmake and everything was very simple there, it was enough to call qmake and pass `-spec` to it. Qmake wrote the necessary paths to variables on its own, and everything worked fine.

Now I am switching to CMake and I am having difficulty invoking CMake. How can I build the application for a specific platform?

- Does CMake have a possibility similar to "spec" in qmake?
- Or I need to manually set all the variables (I could not implement such a method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake-equivalent of the qmake `-spec` option is essentially the `-G` (for "generator") command line [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options). This will tell CMake which [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) to use. The CMake generator is responsible for *generating* the native buildsystem files (e.g. Unix Makefiles, Visual Studio project files, etc.) so it is a platform-dependent setting. For example,

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

Unlike qmake, where you specify a path to the platform/compiler information, you can tell CMake out-right which generator to choose from the list of supported generators. The CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#cmake-generators) conveniently breaks down the list of supported generators into **command line** and **IDE** groups. If you don't explicitly pick a generator, CMake will use a default generator based on the current platform.

CMake also provides additional options (that can be used along with `-G`) to further specify which toolset (`-T`) or platform (`-A`) to use with the generated buildsystem. The toolset and platform specifications can tell the buildsystem which *specific* compiler or SDK to choose. For example, we can tell CMake to prepare a build environment for an application with a `Win32` platform (architecture) with Visual Studio 2019 using this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 ..
```

or we can change the architecture to 64-bit by specify this instead:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..
```

I encourage you to read through the linked documentation to understand more about how you can control CMake's buildsystem and compiler selection settings.